# DBCC PAGE output analysis

Tags: sql-server

I created the following table

```
USE [Test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_3]
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [itemcode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [gain] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [loss] [decimal](18, 5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into dbo.table_3 
values (1,1,1000.0,'28-Feb-2018',null,null)


DBCC IND ('Test','Table_3',-1)
GO
```

The output of DBCC IND command above gave two rows

```
PageFID PagePID IAMFID  IAMPID  ObjectID    IndexID PartitionNumber PartitionID iam_chain_type  PageType    IndexLevel  NextPageFID NextPagePID PrevPageFID PrevPagePID
1   297 NULL    NULL    581577110   0   1   72057594040877056   In-row data 10  NULL    0   0   0   0
1   296 1   297 581577110   0   1   72057594040877056   In-row data 1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Then I used the above output to get page details

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604)
DBCC PAGE ('Test',1,297,1)
GO
```

The output of the same is

> PAGE: (1:297)
>   BUFFER:
>   BUF @0x04797150
>   bpage = 0x07D74000                  bhash = 0x00000000
>   bpageno = (1:297) bdbid = 9                           breferences = 0 
>   bcputicks = 0 bsampleCount = 0                    bUse1 = 26039
>   bstat = 0x10b blog = 0x15adb21c                   bnext = 0x00000000
>   PAGE HEADER:
>   Page @0x07D74000
>   m_pageId = (1:297)                  m_headerVersion = 1
>   m_type = 10 m_typeFlagBits = 0x0                m_level = 0
>   m_flagBits = 0x0 m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = 125   m_indexId
>   (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 256  Metadata: AllocUnitId = 72057594046119936
>   Metadata: PartitionId = 72057594040877056
>   Metadata: IndexId = 0 Metadata: ObjectId = 581577110      m_prevPage =
>   (0:0)                  m_nextPage = (0:0) pminlen = 90
>   m_slotCnt = 2                       m_freeCnt = 6 m_freeData = 8182
>   m_reservedCnt = 0                   m_lsn = (48:296:16) m_xactReserved
>   = 0                  m_xdesId = (0:0)                    m_ghostRecCnt = 0 m_tornBits = 0                      DB Frag ID = 1
>
> Allocation Status
>
> GAM (1:2) = ALLOCATED               SGAM (1:3) = ALLOCATED
>   PFS (1:1) = 0x70 IAM_PG MIXED_EXT ALLOCATED   0_PCT_FULL
>   DIFF (1:6) = CHANGED ML (1:7) = NOT MIN_LOGGED
>
> DATA:
>   Slot 0, Offset 0x60, Length 94, DumpStyle BYTE
>   Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =
>   Record Size = 94
>   Memory Dump @0x0D52C060
>   00000000:   00005e00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
>   ..^................. 00000014:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000  .................... 00000028:   00000000 01002801 00000100
>   00000000 00000000  ......(............. 0000003C:   00000000 00000000
>   00000000 00000000 00000000  .................... 00000050:   00000000
>   00000000 00000000 0000               ..............
>
> Slot 1, Offset 0xbe, Length 7992, DumpStyle BYTE
>
> Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =
>   Record Size = 7992
>
> Memory Dump @0x0D52C0BE

If there is just one row in the table, how can it have two Slots (Slot 0 and Slot 1, I have not pasted the text for slot 1 as it is huge) ? Since it is a table with 5 fixed data type columns, the size I expect is 2*4 (int)+ 1*3(date) +3*9 (decimal (18,5)) = 38 bytes but the Record Size mentions 94, am I misreading it ?

Follow up question

Based on Dan's comment I have changed the page id and selected 296 this time.

Here is the output of DBCC PAGE ('Test',1,296,1)

> Slot 0, Offset 0x60, Length 45, DumpStyle BYTE
>
> Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP
>   Record Size = 45
>
> Memory Dump @0x0CC1C060
>
> 00000000:   10002a00 01000000 01000000 0100e1f5 05000000 
>   ..*...........áõ.... 00000014:   00f03d0b 00000100 01000000 1c000000
>   60a29f07  .ð=.............`¢. 00000028:   d8660600 30
>   Øf..0

Shouldn't come out to be 38 (as per my understanding explained above) instead of 45 ?

Comment: You need to specify 296 (the PagePID from second row of DBCC_IND) instead of 297 (which is the IAM page).

Answer (score 0):

Record header (4 bytes long)

```
-2 bytes of record metadata 
-2 bytes pointer to null bitmap
```

Fixed length data (38 bytes long)

```
-8 bytes per int
-3 bytes per date
-27 bytes per decimal
```

Null bitmap (3 bytes long)

```
-2 bytes for count of columns in the record
-1 byte to store one bit per column in the record
```

Sum is 45 bytes